# Appropriate site for questions about running an IT company and IT careers

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation, site-usage

I have several questions that I would like to see answered regarding the running of an IT company, as well as several questions about IT careers.

It seems that these questions don't quite fit in at either Stack Overflow or Server Fault.

Do you have plans for a site for questions of this type or would any of the below be appropriate for one of the existing sites?

I.e.:

- We are migrating from [ClearCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_ClearCase) to another [VCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) - for companies that have made this transition, what factors did they find important in selecting another VCS tool, and what practices did they find eased the transition?
- Our small privately-held software company is being acquired by another privately held company, but management refuses to allow employees to see the terms sheet from the acquiring company.  Is the terms sheet something that would normally be public information or is it typical that this information would be private?
- When interviewing for a management position for a small private software company, what is the best way to get an understanding of the financial governance practices that the company uses - is it okay to request the chart of accounts that the company uses in its accounting?

Comment: Sounds like you should consider making a management-oriented site (not specifically for software-company management as your second question really has nothing to do with software companies) when StackExchange comes around in September.

Comment: The third question also has nothing to do with software. These are the "boat programming" questions of software companies. They don't have anything to do with software even when you stick the word "software" in front of "company".

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110852/289691, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129355/289691, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211159/289691, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295524/289691,

Answer (score 4):

You're right, these really don't fit any of our sites very well. The first one might fit in with SO because it's VCS related.

Though it's not based on the SO engine, might I suggest asking these on the [Business of Software board](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/?biz) that Joel Spolsky has? Barring that you could try Super User as it's sort of a catch-all for computer topics, but I wouldn't be surprised to see it get closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

The first one sounds good for Stack Overflow - there are already questions there that might provide insightful answers. But the other ones, as Kyle Cronin said, don't belong on any of the current trilogy sites.

Answer (score 0):

> We are migrating from Clearcase to another VCS - for companies that have made this transition, what factors did they find important in selecting another VCS tool, and what practices did they find eased the transition.

SO-suitable programming-tool-related question

> Our small privately held software company is being acquired by another privately held company, but management refuses to allow employees to see the terms sheet from the acquiring company. Is the terms sheet something that would normally be public information or is it typical that this information would be private.

My opinion: unless you're a stockholder it's none of your business.

> When interviewing for a management position for a small private software company, what is the best way to get an understanding of the financial governance practices that the company uses - is it okay to request the chart of accounts that the company uses in it's accounting?

My opinion: I don't think the chart of accounts is necessarily relevant (think Enron) but if you do then by all means ask them about it.