# Where can you ask about Career Advice?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

The [Help Center of Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) specifically says not to ask  for career advice but people do it anyway.  Should I consider the Help Center outdated or only loosely enforced?

And what about a career advice site on the network?  There are 70+ sites, and most of them are for relatively narrow interests (which is not a criticism, I enjoy looking through the many sections).  A career section seems like it would be very popular.  Also, a careers section would help keep career questions off the other sites.

Comment: Why not ask this on meta.programmers?

Comment: see also: [Where to ask for general advice for young programmers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216589/165773)

Comment: I'm protecting this question because it is attracting ads for career advice websites posted as answers.

Answer (score 22):

I am a moderator on The Workplace.

*Some* questions related to career advice are on-topic for Workplace. However. This is NOT all questions related to career advice.

**Make sure you have a clear, answerable question.** Bad career questions are "what should I do? should I learn skill X? take job Y? go into field Z?" These are nearly impossible to answer and unfortunately are the most common.

**Make sure your question is about work/career but not *a specific job*.**  Questions like "what skills do I need to get a job as an X?" are not on-topic because they are about specific domain areas ranging from software architecture to plumbing to dentistry.

See [this link](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2695/2322) for a better explanation.

Good questions will be focused on asking the how/why related to career questions.

For example, asking "should I work for a startup or big MNC?" is a bad question. Asking [What are the risks and benefits of working at a start up over an established Company](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/11210/2322) is a good question.

Answer (score 14):

There is now [workplace.stackexchange.com](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/), a site "for members of the workforce navigating the professional setting". Workplace has many questions related to career advice, such as

- [Recovering from bad career decisions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1615/recovering-from-bad-career-decisions)
- [How should I approach my boss if I feel I am underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid/)
- [Stuck in a dead-end job, how do I get ahead?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6170/stuck-in-a-dead-end-job-how-do-i-get-ahead)
- [Hitting a ceiling in my career](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/537/hitting-a-ceiling-in-my-career)

Answer (score 6):

While there isn't a specific "career talk" site on the Network, that doesn't mean there couldn't be one. Support your favorite proposal (below). We'll probably have to merge these interests in some way that combines forces and creates an excellent site. Take your pick:

- [Professional Matters](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30887/professional-matters)
- [IT Careers & Training](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12887/it-careers-training)
- [Interviewing & Recruiting](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13418/interviewing-recruiting)
- [Professional Careers & Advice](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/24003/professional-careers-advice)
- [Career Development](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/21141/career-development)

Software Engineering SE (formerly known as Programmers) is *not* a career site unless it is really, really specific to a programmer's issue. Most "programmer career" questions could equally apply to just about any field, and that's why they are not generally accepted on that site.

Comment: Four of these proposals are dead and one is no longer a proposal. It might make sense to delete this answer, since the progs and workplace perspectives are fully covered by Anna's and enderland's, respectively. :)