# Which forum should I ask?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can you ask about Career Advice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110852/where-can-you-ask-about-career-advice)

I posted this question:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122779/software-developer-heading-towards-project-manager

And it was closed. Where should I ask these kind of questions in WWW. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, that type of question does not really fit the Q&A format of the Stackoverflow/Stackexchange family of sites. You might try some programmer-oriented forums that allow extended discussions/threads, maybe the Microsoft forums, or maybe [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/)(?).

Comment: I don't think you're ready for project management.

Comment: @Won't You can't just say that!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a suitable Stack Exchange site for this purpose, because it's really subjective question.

Comment: there is: pm.SO.com

Comment: @Raj excuse me, but what is pm.So.com?

Comment: @Martin He probably means http://pm.stackexchange.com, which is a project management site. I'm not sure what their stance on career questions is, though.

Comment: @AnnaLear thanks, now it's time to explain it a bit more

Comment: @Raj there isn't Stack Exchange site for this purpose, because **no Stack Exchange site is suitable for subjective questions**