# Where to ask for general advice for young programmers?

Tags: support, chat, site-recommendation

I'm thirteen years old (yes I was twelve when I signed up, but I had my parents make my account on my behalf and did not post any personal information, which I believe is legal :-P), and I am very passionate about programming. I have some questions regarding young programmers, and I'm wondering where to ask.

First I want to note a few things, before you say "nowhere; this doesn't fit with the q&a format" (which I do quite a bit :-P):

- I have a specific problem. I'm not going to ask "what should I do now;" there are specific things I want to know. For example, "how can a young programmer do xxx."
- My question applies to a general audience. I'm not going to ask "I've done xxx and want xxx, should I do xxx;" rather, it will apply to all young programmers in general.

Here are the sites I might ask it on:

- Programmers: I've considered asking here. I've seen the famous Venn diagram with "all people," "all careers," "all programmers," and "just you," and I believe that if I make my question general enough, it can apply to **all** young programmers. A question like this seems to be on-topic according to their "what can I ask" guidelines. However, their description says

  > Programmers Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development.

  It's not really about software development, and I'm *certainly* not professional, so that gives me doubts about asking there.
- The Workplace: I'm not sure about this one... it's not really about work, but I suppose it could be in a kind of abstract way ("the work of programming" or something). This seems like the wrong site though.
- Something else? Is there a better site perhaps?

Where on the SE network should I ask this, if at all? Or is this just not suitable to SE in general and I should find somewhere else to ask?

Comment: What kind of question would have a different answer for “young programmers”? If you’re thinking of something equivalentish to “beginning programmers”, use that! If the question doesn’t seem to fit after that replacement, well… it probably doesn’t fit.

Comment: @minitech Well, non-adults do definitely see a vastly different environment, including a programming one. For example, a young programmer can't apply for the vast majority of programming positions/projects/other things, and just don't have access to the same things that adults do. By no means am I asking about beginning programmers, nor do I consider myself one; I'm asking specifically about age.

Comment: I have a hard time coming up with something that would be a good question, but age specific. But perhaps I'm too stuck in SO's context, where I really can't think of a suitable question. Is there anything particular you have in mind?

Comment: If it’s job-related, The Workplace and Programmers both sound like better places. Still… do you have an example in mind?

Comment: @Bart Well, I was thinking something like "how can a young programmer do %s", with something like participate in a project, become recognized, do something useful, etc., basically, anything that an adult can do but children can't.

Comment: The thing is though that it isn't really a matter of being young. On the internet no one knows you're a dog. If you want to join an open source project, join. If you want to get recognized, participate on SO, blog, twit on Tweeter about your dev-related things, etc. But that's the same for adults.

Comment: @minitech Okay, a more specific question could be "how can I do something useful ex. Work on a project or help in a position or something as a young programmer. Sorry for vague examples; I will elaborate when I actually have a keyboard :-P

Comment: @Bart Well I can't, for example, apply for a programming job at my age. That's not what I'm trying to do, but age can limit programmers. Sorry for vague examples; I'll elaborate later (see previous comment)

Comment: Kids these days. I had a programming job when I was your age. I had to slog through hundreds of lines of VB.NET code every morning on the job for thirteen cents an hour! Thirteen *Canadian* cents! While it was raining! (This entire comment is actually true BTW) Anyways, yes, that sounds like something for Programmers. Not that I really know what belongs on Programmers.

Comment: Agreed with Bart: I had no inkling you were a̶ ̶d̶o̶g̶ thirteen. All I see is an individual who seems to be a coherent communicator and competent at programming. You want to contribute to some projects, it's not likely to matter that you're young.

Comment: @Josh and all Thanks for answering my question :-P, but that's not why I asked this question. If I have a similar question, where should I ask it?

Comment: I know that's not the answer to what you actually posted here; that's why it's a comment. :þ

Comment: Parenting! Just ask weird 3rd person questions…

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you have sufficient privileges, safe places for "drafting" questions like that are Programmers and Workplace [chat](/questions/tagged/chat) rooms ([Whiteboard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard) and [Water Cooler](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler), respectively).

Being free from topical / subjectivity limitations of Q&A sites, chat rooms allow one to discuss problems that might be not good fit for main site. Site regulars frequenting the rooms mentioned above can offer help and advice on how to "build" a question that would be topical and welcome at the main site.