# Where to ask programming related workplace question

Tags: support, site-recommendation

My question is about a) an interview which I would place on "Workplace" and b) also uses many programming related terms, which would best suit "Stackoverflow".

The question background is like this (I did not find a suitable title yet):

1. One of my employees is working on source code of a useful application. He's a beginner, so he doesn't write the best code.
2. The application is not related to the business of our company, so I take the initiative of making the code open source, so that anyone can benefit from it.
3. a) The employee refuses to create a GitHub repository, because it might have negative impact on his future career or b) the employee has left the company and can no longer create a GitHub repository.
4. Since I have taken the initiative of making it open source, I become responsible to actually make it happen. However, I have no time to clean up everything in the code.

**The question to find a site for**: Would my initiative of making a *useful* application open source have positive impact in an interview or negative impact because the code quality is low? Consider that the initial commit is made by me.

Since the programming related amount is quite high, I wonder whether "Workplace" is the really the correct place to get a suitable answer.

**Is there a SE site to ask this question?**

Comment: as you have sufficient privileges, best place to draft and tune such a question would be [Programmers or Workplace chat rooms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216617/165773)

Comment: Your question is primarily opinion-based, since we really have no way of knowing how prospective employers will react to your application.  It is therefore not on-topic anywhere on SE. Gnat is right; try one of the chat rooms.

Comment: @gnat / Robert: do you want to give this as an answer?

Answer (score -4):

This is basically an interview question to determine your psychological mindset and has got nothing to do with programming at all. So, this won't be a good question for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and would be off-topic as well.

This wouldn't fit the scope of [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) as well because of the same reasons (and they specifically mention to not ask such questions there in their help-center).

[Workplace.SE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) looks like a fine candidate for such questions. So, you should ask the question on Workplace.SE. If you think you can generalize the situation so that it becomes applicable for other workplaces as well, great, go ahead and generalize it so that it fits other workplaces too.

Comment: This is *clearly* more appropriate for programmers.SE than it is for workplace. It should be asked well though and OP should make sure it's not on there already. Basically it's "how does mixed quality open source work impact a job application?"

Comment: Questions about specific jobs are off-topic on Workplace, and once you strip this down from a programming question you're left with "is it better or worse to show my poor-quality open-source work" -- which you could ask, I guess, but you'd need to make it less subjective.

Comment: Looks like I am looking at the question from a different perspective.. Anyways, I would take a break, re-read the question and comments tomorrow and re-assess my stand.

Comment: @djechlin: How does it fit to Programmers, which is for "software requirements, software architecture and design, algorithms and data structures, development methodologies and processes, software engineering management, quality assurance and testing, software licensing"?

Comment: @MonicaCellio: [This meta question on Workplace.SE](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/1636/17074) says that questions are on-topic even if it applies to a specific profession. So, this question should be fine there, though I agree that the less subjective it is, the better.