# In which Stack Exchange site can one ask questions about ITIL?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

In which Stack Exchange site can one find/ask questions about ITIL?

Some context:

> The Information Technology Infrastructure Library (ITIL), is a set of practices for IT service management (ITSM) that focuses on aligning IT services with the needs of business.

Small enterprises do not need much effort in management, cooperation and understanding. But when they grow in to large enterprises is a different story, with the separation of duties, all hell breaks loose and things get confusing... ITIL may be a good starting tool to bring order in to chaos.

Comment: Is it Project Management oriented or hardware/software oriented? I'm not familiar with it

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL I rather meant "is it a method of handling software resources?", not that it actually was a piece of software

Comment: Ben Brocka: Neither, its about organization and way the work is done in IT to give good service for business people.

Answer (score 2):

My gut instinct says [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/about), which is (AIUI) *the* SE site for IT professionals.

> ### What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Server Fault is for Information Technology Professionals needing
> expert answers related to managing computer systems in a
> **professional capacity**.
>
> If your question is about...
>
> - Server and Business Workstation operating systems, hardware, software and virtualization
> - Enterprise storage, backup, and disaster recovery
> - Network routing, switches, and firewalls
> - Operations, maintenance, and monitoring
>
> and it is *not* about...
>
> - **Anything in a home setting**
> - Product, service, or learning material recommendations
> - Career, salary, personnel, employment, or formal education
> - Licensing, legal advice, and circumvention of security or policy
> - Unauthorized hacking, password cracking, or system misuse
>
> ...then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Comment: AIUI = _As I use it_???

Comment: [As I understand it.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/AIUI)

Comment: Thanks, that's a textism that I haven't come across yet.

Comment: [NP](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/NP#Abbreviation). `:)`

Answer (score 2):

I would say [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/) or [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/).