# Is there a question site about ITIL v3?

Tags: feature-request, site-recommendation

I am interested in and learning [ITIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITIL), which is a HUGE framework and the de facto standard for developing IT services, which you can also get certified for and has (I think) many learners out there.

How is my question different from the "possible duplicates"?

There are many sites about technology and IT, but not that much (or no side) about how to design, manage, organise IT services with a business aspect.

I asked my question about ITIL on the "project management" Stack Exchange site, but it doesn't fit there quite well (was said to me). And there are not many sites where my question could fit. (I haven't found any, but project management).

So on which site should I ask a question about ITIL?

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate of [another question from 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129355/323179), but I think its answers may be really out of date.

Comment: Depends on your question, looking at [ITIL](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=itil&page=1)  across the network. Keep in mind that questions that ask for personal advice (as in: what do i need to learn, what exam to take etc) are off-topic across most of the SE sites as such questions and its answers have little to no value for future visitors.

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy, thanks but there isn't the answer I searched for... looks like there is no side where ITIL-questions fit...

Comment: @gnat thanks but this is not a duplicate, it defers from it because it hasn't to do much with IT directly, but more with management, business and organisation.