# Where would I ask a question about managing a team of developers?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a stack exchange Q&A site for the management of teams of developers?

Comment: May be: http://pm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific?  What kinds of management questions are you looking about?  Are they likely to be very specific to managing programmers, or are they largely just management questions where the employees just happen to be programmers?

Comment: Workplace.stackexchange.com or pm.stackexchange.com spring to mind.

Comment: @rene (not the downvoter): does not show any research effort, is unclear, and not useful.  I certainly agree with Servy's comment asking for more information. Until then, the question is a bit vague and could easily suggest the wrong site.  Its an indication to the OP that the question needs some attention.

Comment: Apologies for not being as specific as I should have been. The question was intended specifically for managing programmers. With hindsight it should really apply to management in general.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there a stack exchange Q&A site for the management of teams of developers?

If your questions relate to more general management, The Workplace ([link](http://workplace.stackexchange.com)) is your best bet.

If it will be very specific to developers, Programmers is best as shown [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211161/193412).

Note that in my experience with both sites, many if not most questions asked from this perspective which seem focused on developers are *actually* not-specific to programmers and as a result are better suited for The Workplace.

Source: [very active](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/2322/enderland) on Workplace and spend <s>far too much</s> time in the [Programmers chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard).

Answer (score 2):

With the information you gave, you have two obvious options.

### Option 1

I would ask this question on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

> Programmers Stack Exchange is a site for professional programmers who are interested in getting expert answers on conceptual questions about software development. If you have a question about...

Also there is a little trick there to know if you are off-topic and you fall within the right range.

Ask your question there if it is really about developers.

> [image]

If your question isn't about the developers

### Option 2

If you feel your question really isn't about the developers but more about how to act as the team leader, then I think the [Project Manager Beta site](https://pm.stackexchange.com/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Couldn't find the team leader beta site even after searching Area51...

Comment: Where would I ask a question about managing a team of hot-dog-makers?

If you can replace the word developer with hot-dog-makers and not lose context on the question, *It's not about developers*.

Comment: Programmers has a history of closing off topic questions that are not about programming.  But the good news is if the dont want the question they will usually ship it to someone else wether its a good question or not.

Comment: @Chad - while it may not be as evident as we would hope, there is a concerted effort within Programmers to make sure we don't migrate poor questions.  And I'll acknowledge there have been questionable (okay, they were crap) migrations to TW in the past.  We're working to make those the exception, not the norm.  Please feel free to drop into the Whiteboard and point out questionable migrations when you see them.

Comment: @GlenH7  -Thank you that is all we ask