# Where can I ask about management and leadership?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm about to start a new job as project manager in a electronic engineering team, but I have no real experience (just some standard learning at the university).

I'm sure that at some point, I will have some questions or some points to discuss with. First I will ask other project manager in my company, but if I want to go further I may ask the Stack Exchange community. Where should I post these questions? Since it's not going to be purely electronic questions, it won't fit on [the electronics engineering Stack Exchange site](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour).

The kind of question I may ask are:

- How to deal with a negative person in a team
- What kind of tools are useful in team management?

Comment: [workplace.se]? Is it about how to do your job? I'm not sure what your questions would be about. Could you think up a sample question?

Comment: That's probably already been asked on workplace.

Comment: @catija why did you add two question marks in your answer? Was it supposed to be sarcastic or something? Do you think he already knew the answer and was just passing a question to troll people? Do you not think he sincerely wants an answer and potentially didn't want to later get sarcastically commented at on one of those other sites so he asked it here first? Does that make sense?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For specific questions about project management, there's [**Project Management**](https://pm.stackexchange.com/) (currently in Beta).

> The site is for project management practitioners, academics and amateur theorists. This is a site about the field of project management for people who love the subject. Our site includes the following topics:
>
> This site is about...
>
> - Project Management Practices and Theory
> - Agile
> - Scrum
> - PRINCE2
> - Tool Usage in Project Management
> - Project Manager Career Advancement

---

For personnel-related, non-project-management work issues, [**The Workplace**](https://workplace.stackexchange.com) could be an alternative.

> The Workplace Stack Exchange is a Q&A site about the workplace and other career-related topics. With your help we're working to build a library to every question about the workplace related to:
>
> - Finding employment (resumes/CV/cover letters, recruiters, hiring-managers, interviews, negotiations, etc.)
> - Maintaining employment (promotions, pay increases, harassment, bullying, poor working conditions, communication problems, etc.)
> - Leadership in the workplace (motivating people, encouraging people, making decisions, holding hard conversations, intervening in unproductive situations, asking for and giving help, etc.)
> - Terminating employment (notice period, breaking the news, handing over work, reference letters, relieving letters, etc.)

Answer (score 6):

I'm actually not sure if this a valid answer on meta, but I'll post this anyway. Since the question didn't specifically ask for which Communities on Stack Exchange, I'm going to share other ones that I know which aren't on here. The ones listed by ale in the other answer are definitely the right answer for SE.

- [Slack Community Rands-Leadership](https://randsinrepose.com/welcome-to-rands-leadership-slack/)
- [Slack Community Engineering Management](https://engmanagers.github.io/)
- [Reddit Tech Leader Community](https://www.reddit.com/r/TechLeader/)

All of those focus on leadership and specifically provide answers to the types of problems you proposed.